# VLC not closing properly

Tags: vlc-media-player

When I close VLC it doesn't stop playing the video and the only way I can stop it from playing is via the task manager.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

My computer is Windows 7 and I'm running VLC 2.0.1

Comment: I do not know a fix for it, but I would try a different render method , and see if it changed anything. Make sure that it is not set for overly high priority in task manager, check if it is running in any form of "compatibility" modes.

Comment: *How* do you close VLC? Clicking the `[x]`? `Ctrl+Q`? `Alt+F4`?

Comment: Is this a known issue? Not sure how to change the render method... Task manager has default priority. No compatibility mode

Comment: The x in the corner

Comment: preferences -> video -> output modules

(make sure to enable the "advanced options" in the bottom right corner first to see this options) The idea would be that different render methods use different paths, and hardware or not, or DX or not, or 3D type renders or not. Mabey some method of render is locking something up. Check also your CPU and GPU use? For some extrodinary or odd usage? Like many things it could be a driver issue, filters, codecs, and other things involved in the whole process of either the audio or the video.